# unchek checkbox with another button in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

I'm learning Reactjs and trying to make my own multiple checkbox like the existing multiple checkbox packages, but I'm confused at the final stage to make the checkbox unchecked when I press the checkbox indicator button,

[image]
[image]

```js
const ListProduct = () => {

    // Checkbox Handle
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState([]);

    // Add/Remove checked item from list
    const handleCheck = (event) => {
        var updatedList = [...checked];
        if (event.target.checked) {
        updatedList = [...checked, event.target.value];
        } else {
        updatedList.splice(checked.indexOf(event.target.value), 1);
        }
        setChecked(updatedList);
        
    };

    // Generate string of checked items
    const renderFilters  = () => {
        return checked.map((item) => {
            if (item.length >= 1){
                return (
                        <Badge className="filter-list-indikator" bg="secondary" key={item} onClick={handleCheck}>
                            {item}
                        </Badge>
                );
            } else {
                return null
            }
        })
    }
```

```
<div className="d-flex" key={1}>
      <input type="checkbox" onChange={handleCheck} value="3 Seater"/>
      <label>3 Seater</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Usually this behavior is achieved with a radio button rather than a check box by the way. Check box from a UI/UX standpoint implies that you can select them both

Comment: yes I want to make it like that, the goal is to make multiple checkboxes like the filter feature in online stores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One quick fix

```
<div className="d-flex" key={1}>
      <input type="checkbox" checked={checked?.includes("3 Seater")} onChange={handleCheck} value="3 Seater"/>
      <label>3 Seater</label>
</div>
```

a more flexible solution will include dynamic checkboxes

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Badge, Checkbox, Tag } from "antd";


const data = [
  {
    id: 0,
    title: "2 Seater",
    key: "2 Seater",
    checked: true
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "3 Seater",
    key: "3 Seater",
    checked: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "4 Seater",
    key: "4 Seater",
    checked: true
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "5 Seater",
    key: "5 Seater",
    checked: true
  }
];

const App () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(data);

  const onChange = (item: any, e) => {
    console.log(`checked = ${e.target.checked}`, item);
    const checked = e.target.checked;
    setItems((checks) => {
      return checks?.map((e) => (e.id === item.id ? { ...e, checked } : e));
    });
  };

  const checkedItems = items?.filter((e) => e.checked);

  const onBadgeClick = (item) => {
    setItems((checks) => {
      return checks?.map((e) =>
        e.id === item.id ? { ...e, checked: false } : e
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      {items.map((item, i) => {
        return (
          <div key={item.id}>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              checked={item.checked}
              onChange={(e) => onChange(item, e)}
            ></input>
            <label>{item.title}</label>
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <div>
        {checkedItems?.map((item) => {
          return (
            <Tag closable key={item.id} onClose={() => onBadgeClick(item)}>
              {item.title}
            </Tag>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Hope it guides you to a better solution

Comment: thanks it work,
but html tags become a red color and if i hihglight show (property) React.InputHTMLAttributs<HTMLInputElement>.checked?: boolean | undifined)

Comment: Welcome, I am trying to understand the problem, may be you can post the code or an image, but you can experiment with the working example in [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/check-all-antd-5-0-7-forked-927euv?file=/demo.tsx)